# Is the whole Zend Framework stack rebuilt for each request?

Tags: php, web-applications, zend-framework2

I am working on a web application built with php and zend framework 2. I come from a Java EE background. It seems to me that for each http request the whole zend application stack is being rebuilt, reading a load of config files from disk, constructing all my services and whatnot. Is this correct? If so this seems rather strange and inefficient to me compared to the Java EE approach of having a load of application services that are initialized on web server start up and then have a lifetime across many requests. Seeing as the browser is making lots of little Ajax requests isn't this php/zend approach horribly slow? Do I need a paradigm shift in the way I approach web application design?

Comment: This is framework-independant. Everything on PHP is per request. All files are read anew. This is where opcode-caches come into play so we have all relevant stuff inside the memory already. Caching is a huge part of web development in php.

Comment: I see, thanks for confirming this is the PHP way.

Comment: @Sam I think you wanted to say that all needed files are read anew. As I described below, not all files of the application and of zf2 are being read for each request, but only the ones that contain initialized classes or configurations. And even those won't be read from disc as you described correctly, they come from memory or cache in most cases, tanks to apache, view caching, config caching and so on.

Answer (score 1):

- ZF2 can use caching to improve performance , the configuration also
  can be cached as well   .
- any service or class in `ZF2` shouldn't be constructed on every request , for example a db connection (ZF2 won't try to connect to db unless you are really doing something to the db server)

another example :

suppose you had an REST API , you need to use on one controller only , no need to construct this api on every request , you alternatively ask you module's service manager to construct that object for you on that controller only .

take a look at this blog , it might help you : http://www.masterzendframework.com/articles-2/zend-framework-2-core-concepts-understanding-dependency-injection

or http://akrabat.com/ or the ZF2 Team leader : Matthew Weier O'Phinney  http://mwop.net/

**(if I understand your question, sorry if not)**

Answer (score 1):

it's correct that php is not running in an environment, like java does.
This means that your php application is beeing **initialized** on each request.

> It seems to me that for each http request the whole zend application stack is being rebuilt

But this is not correct. The initialization of your php- / zf2- application is not that heavy as you may think, when you're coming from java.
Don't think of something like a tomcat server being rebooted on each request. The whole Zend Framework is also not beeing loaded and your application classes aren't as well.
Only the classes that are needed for your specific request are being loaded.

PHP Frameworks make use of Autoloaders for this, so if you call new MyClass() in your app, that class will be loaded. And even the file containing "MyClass" is not being loaded from disc in many cases, but from ram-memory or bytecode cache.

If your server is set up correctly, the zf2 skeleton application for example will be loaded in a few milliseconds.

**What about your services that need to be ready for your application?**

They're nothing more than a "key" in an associative array, inside your configuration. When your application needs a service for your specific request, it will find the entry in your configuration array extremely fast. The Service will be initialized from a factory method or a factory class only for this request, but only the specific one which is needed.

Facebook is using php as well. It doesn't need a minute for each request right? If php worked the way you're thinking of it at the moment, it would take minutes or hours I guess - or just end up in a timeout :)